# OCaml Day of Year Operator Program

Tags: ocaml

Write an equality operator (call it =/) that works correctly on the `yearday` type of Example 11.38. (You may need to look up the rules that govern the occurrence of leap years.)

Example 11.38: `type yearday = YMD of int * int * int | YD of int * int;;`

I am having a hard time working this in OCaml and would love to see how this can be done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You should read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and provide us with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order for other users to help you.

Comment: Example 11.38 in what?  Also, you shouldn't expect people here to go and look up rules, even if you provide a link.  Exactly which rules matter to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to write an operator is `let (=/) a b = ...`.

For your problem you need to convert YMD and YD values to a common value (eg, YD)